# Плавное перемещение объекта пальцем в две стороны

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть такой код он перемещает объект по оси Z, но он перемещает только в одну сторону не важно куда движется палец в вправо влево, а нужно чтобы в зависимости в какую сторону движется палец! Как это сделать?

```
using UnityEngine;


public class Follower : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region ================================= PRIVATE FIELDS

    private readonly float _speed = 0.1f;
    private Vector2 _startPos;

    #endregion

    #region ============================== PRIVATE METHODS

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    _startPos = touch.position;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    var dir = touch.position - _startPos;
                    var pos = transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, dir.y);
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * _speed);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: а почему здесь `var pos = transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, dir.y);` Вы берете y-координату `dir.y`, а не x-координату?

Comment: Чтобы она двигалась когда смарфон находится в вертикальном положении

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в координатах, которые вы получаете из тача. `touch.position` - возвращает позицию в экранных координатах, а это от (0,0) в левом нижнем углу, до (ширина, высота) в верхнем правом. Соответственно, вы всегда плюсуете положительное число и персонаж никогда не пойдёт влево или вниз.

Экранные координаты нужно привести к мировым через метод камеры [ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). Если у вас есть камера с тэгом MainCamera, то приведение может выглядеть вот так:

```
var direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
```

В переменной direction будет находиться координаты тача в мировом пространстве и работая с ними вы уже получите более ожидаемое поведение)

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно